# read file line by line and replace parts with boto3 in AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, replace, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm struggling with AWS lambda boto3:
I want to read a file line by line and replace a dedicated expressions in each line

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

print(event)

bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)

for text in obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').splitlines():
    if "ABC" in text:
        print(text)
```

the code works well and the logs show me only the lines I'm interested in. Now I tried to replace certain expressions in the line but either "replace or sub" did work:

example line: `ABC  <123>  <abg 46547>  <!ab123>`

I want to come to: `ABC_123_46547_ab123`

is there any regular expression for boto3 to replace line parts?
Thanks for help!

Comment: Can you show us how you tried to replace text? FYI replacing X with Y in a string has nothing to do boto3.

Comment: first idea:
if "ABC" in Text:
text.replace("  <","_").replace(">  <","_").replace("!","").replace(">","")

second was to create a list item with all expressions to be replaced
dic = {" ":"", "<":"_", ">":"", "!":""}
new = [dic.get(n, n) for n in text]
print(new)

Comment: It seems reasonable to use s = s.replace("<", "").replace(">", "")... Is this not working for you? If not, show us some code (above) and tell us what the (bad) result is.

Comment: for text in obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').splitlines():
        if 'ABC' in text:
            line = text.replace('>  <abg ',';')
            print(line)

gives the result:
ABC  <123>  <abg 46547>  <!ab123>
without any change

Comment: could it be that I would have to replace every item separately like replace('>','').replace('<','')...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the one example you supplied, you haven't indicated any particular set of rules for how you want to substitute strings, so I'm having to guess what your intentions are.

Here are few options. The 1st is a brute force approach that simply performs literal replacements. The 2nd and 3rd use regular expressions for a more generic and extensible approach.

```
import re

# in:  ABC  <123>  <abg 46547>  <!ab123>
# out: ABC_123_46547_ab123
#
# Need to substitute the following:
# "  <abg " with "_"
# "  <!" with "_"
# "  <" with "_"
# ">" with ""

# ------------------------------------------------
# 1st option
# ------------------------------------------------
s1 = "ABC  <123>  <abg 46547>  <!ab123>"

s2 = s1 \
    .replace("  <abg ", "_") \
    .replace("  <!", "_") \
    .replace("  <", "_") \
    .replace(">", "")

print("Option #1: literal")
print("\tbefore : {}".format(s1))
print("\tafter  : {}".format(s2))

# ------------------------------------------------
# 2nd option
# ------------------------------------------------
s3 = s1

replacements_literal = [
    ("  <abg ", "_"),
    ("  <!", "_"),
    ("  <", "_"),
    (">", "")
]

for old, new in replacements_literal:
    s3 = re.sub(old, new, s3)

print("\nOption #2: literal, with loop")
print("\tbefore : {}".format(s1))
print("\tafter  : {}".format(s3))

# ------------------------------------------------
# 3rd option
# ------------------------------------------------
s4 = s1

replacements_regex = [
    (" *<[a-z]+ *", "_"),
    (" *<!", "_"),
    (" *<", "_"),
    (">", "")
]

for old, new in replacements_regex:
    s4 = re.sub(old, new, s4)

print("\nOption #3: regex, with loop")
print("\tbefore : {}".format(s1))
print("\tafter  : {}".format(s4))
```

The output looks like this:

```
Option #1: literal
        before : ABC  <123>  <abg 46547>  <!ab123>
        after  : ABC_123_46547_ab123

Option #2: literal, with loop
        before : ABC  <123>  <abg 46547>  <!ab123>
        after  : ABC_123_46547_ab123

Option #3: regex, with loop
        before : ABC  <123>  <abg 46547>  <!ab123>
        after  : ABC_123_46547_ab123
```